# Does chrome store click focus internally?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, focus

While using chrome I'm using `document.activeElement` to keep track of an element in focus. The default element is `document.body`.

I'm using cmd + down/up to scroll a container element up and down. When I click into the container, I can use command + up/down to scroll to the top and bottom of the container (`document.activeElement = body` here). However when I click out of the container (onto some other element) I'm unable to use cmd + up/down to scroll the container anymore (`document.activeElement = body` still).

The above makes perfect sense behaviour wise, but why does `document.activeElement` stay the same? How am I able to get different scrolling behaviour when it appears that the 'focus' is staying the same?

Is there some sort of hidden browser click focus?
Is `document.activeElement` not an accurate way of tracking focus?

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/sgregory8/pen/dyWXOWW)